# How to run github action only when a specific file is changed

Tags: github, github-actions

I want my workflow to run only when the Dockerfile is changed. I do not want it to run when a tag is pushed.

When I do the following, the workflow never gets run, even if i commit/push a change to my Dockerfile.

```
name: Publish Docker

on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'Dockerfile'
    tags-ignore:
      - '*'
```

Comment: Are the changes to `Dockefile` made in a PR or in default branch?

Comment: What does your directory structure look like? Do you have a `Dockerfile` on the root of your repo? If the Dockerfile is in some nested directory then you should use `'**/Dockerfile'` paths filter. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#filter-pattern-cheat-sheet and its subsequent sections for official examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushbranchestagsbranches-ignoretags-ignore) it says:

> If you define only tags/tags-ignore or only branches/branches-ignore, the workflow won't run for events affecting the undefined Git ref.

This means you have to specify a **branch** as well. Either an actual branch  from your repository or a wildcard pattern.

Your workflow should then look something like this.

```
name: Publish Docker
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop # or a pattern like "*" for including all branches
    paths:
      - Dockerfile
    tags-ignore:
      - "*"
```